# Understanding how buffer operation works

Tags: project-reactor

```
Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(100))
        .map(i -> 0)
        .buffer(Duration.ofMillis(200))
        .filter(list1 -> list1.size() != 2)
        .subscribe(System.out::println,
                      Throwable::printStackTrace, System.out::println);
```

The above code prints: (at least for the first minute): `[0]`.

Why? I wasn't expecting any printing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## There is only one guarantee from the `.interval` operator and that is that on each specified interval of time the task of generating `onNext` event will be scheduled.

## Unfortunately, there is no guaranty that scheduled task will be executed just in time right after submission.

That is because of undeterminated behaviors of underlying `Scheduler`. 
`Flux.interval` is in other words operator which schedule some event and repeat it over the time. The problem here, that any scheduled operation relies on invocation of the `Thread` on which that operation is scheduled. In case of Reactor, it is a group of thread or in other words ThreadPool (in Reactor world it is `Scheduler`). The problem here is that execution of operation may happen a bit later (but not earlier), there are no guarantees for that since in case of Thread there is a chance that underlying system scheduler may give execution time to another Thread or another execution, so dedicated `Thread` will starve for the CPU cycles, or in case of ThreadPool there is a ThreadPool's queue and in turn there is a chance that there will be another, more important tasks which will be executed earlier.

All that means that interval will be late. In turn, it means that there is a chance that 3 task will be in the buffer. All that `interval` guarantees is that the interval task will be scheduled each specified interval (in your case it is 200 ms)

Comment: Excellent. Thanks, Oleh.

Comment: Man, you are always welcome :) Ping me if you have any other questions ;)